# How to get id using react and from redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am getting id of single product  from backend using match.params but I got error please help me to solve this error

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import "./ProductDetail.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails } from "../../actions/productActions";

const ProductDetail = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetail
  );

  useEffect(
    () => {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
    },
    [dispatch, match.params.id]
  );
```

I am getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

```
 | useEffect(
  15 |   () => {
  16 |     dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
> 17 |   },
     | ^  18 |   [dispatch, match.params.id]
  19 | );
```

> please provide the solution of this or any other way to do this ??

Comment: Where are you rendering `<ProductDetail  />` and what props are you passing to it? Is it only `match`? (e.g. `<ProductDetail match={{ params: { id: 0 } }} />`)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding null coallescing operators to `match`

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(match?.params?.id));
    },
    [dispatch, match.params.id]
  );
```

Also it would be usefull to check if you are ever getting `params` and `id` from match with a `console.log(match)` somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ProductDetail` is a dynamic page and you need to access to the params id.

```
import {  useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(
    () => {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
    },
    [dispatch,id]
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use useParams instead of match

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import './productDetails.css'
import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel'
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { getProductDetails } from '../../actions/productAction'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'


const ProductDetail = ({ match }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
        (state) => state.productDetails
      );

  useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(getProductDetails(id))
    },[dispatch,id])
```